# MYSQL/MariaDB - This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

I try to transfer my python script for the database from SQLite to MariaDB.

This is the code that i use.

`UPDATE users SET x = (%s) WHERE id IN (select id FROM users WHERE user_id = (%s) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)`

I got this error
`mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1235 (42000): This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`

How can i fix this error?

Comment: Welcome on S.O. Please post your MariaDB version

Comment: Version - mariadb-10.8.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use multiple-table UPDATE syntax.

```
UPDATE users 
NATURAL JOIN ( SELECT id 
               FROM users 
               WHERE user_id = (%s) 
               ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ) criteria
SET x = (%s);
```